# Delta tables & base table

Tags: arcgis-server, versioning

What is the difference between a delta table and a base table?
I am confused by these two words.

Delta tables

> The adds and deletes tables for a dataset are collectively referred to
>   as the delta tables because they store changes made to the dataset.

Base tables

> The base table is the core table of a feature class. It contains all
>   the nonspatial attributes and, if using a SQL geometry type, the
>   spatial attribute as well.
>
> The term base table is used to differentiate this core table from
>   other side tables, such as the delta tables, ArcSDE XML tables, or the
>   `f` and `s` tables used by the `sdebinary` geometry storage type.
>
> When you look at a feature class through your database management
>   system's user interface, you see the base table. For example, if your
>   `geodatabase` contains a versioned feature class named `prj_sites`,
>   you will find a table named `prj_sites` in your database. That table
>   is the base table.
>
> Base tables are also called business tables.

Comment: "Delta" is used in the context of the Greek letter denoting "change".  Please **edit** the question to specify that you are using ArcGIS, and post a proper credit to the definitions you quoted by providing a URL.

Comment: yes I am use ArcGIS

Comment: Please do not hide critical information in comments. The response to requests for clarification should be implemented by **editing the question**.  You still haven't cited the document you quoted. Please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand how GIS SE works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you're talking about ArcGIS.

The base table would include the data that was originally loaded into the feature class. As you make edits which include adding, deleting, or changing feature geometry or attributes, entries are added to the delta tables.

When you view the feature class, the software shows you a combination of the base table (any unchanged features) plus updates compiled from the delta tables. "Delta" is often used to represent a "change" in mathematics, thus it's used to represent the additions/deletions/change tables.

You can reconcile and post to "push to base" the changes. That will clear the delta tables and permanently update the base tables.

Compressing the feature class also will push any changes common to all versions to the base table.

Comment: +1 good answer, although I'd add that (AFAIK) it's a *Compress* that pushes the delta data through to the base, not the Reconcile, and other versions can hold up these changes moving fully to base.  Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Midavalo No, "compress" only eliminates the segments in the state tree which do not branch.  It's the "post" of "reconcile/post" which forces deltas into the base table.

Comment: @Vince My experience disagrees with this - a Reconcile/Post submits your changes from your Version into SDE.Default, but does not push them into the *base table* until a compress occurs.  Your changes are available to display from the delta table through ArcMap etc. once they are Reconciled and Posted, but may not appear in the base table via the database management system's user interface until after a compress, particularly if there are other versions being used at the same time.

Comment: Don't confuse SDE.Default with the base table - they can be different.  Esri provides versioned views for this - usually suffixed with `_evw` - to pull the delta data and base data together to give you the most up-to-date data

Comment: @Vince I am now concerned that if I'm wrong (which is a strong possibility) there is potentially something very wrong with my database

Comment: [Versioning 101](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0110/versioning101.html) says `A compress also moves entries in delta tables common to all versions into the base tables`

Comment: yes i talk about ArcGIS///Thank you but,how can i see these table

Comment: ArcGIS tools hide the tables used to implement optimistic long-term transactions (versioning), archiving, and various geometry implementations as *distractions* to using the data model. You'd need to use RDBMS tools to see these tables. *Using* them is handled by the geodatabase model of ArcObjects. Direct access to the implementation tables is discouraged due to the complexity (read-only) and likelihood of geodatabase corruption (read-write). If, after reading all the documentation, you still have questions, you should ask a new question.